HTTP Controller in ASP.NET doesn't post/get any Requests
I have been trying to make test connection to an API controller on ASP.NET (with .NET 8) using curl locally, but i have not get any requests received to the server despite all the code seems to be right:
Here is InternController.cs code:
using backendApp.Data;
using backendApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace backendApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class InternController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public InternController(IWebHostEnvironment environment, DataContext context)
        {
            _environment = environment;
            _context = context;
            _logger = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole()).CreateLogger<InternController>();
        }

        // ...

        [HttpGet("listthemall")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ListAllInterns()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Listing all interns...");
            return Ok("Hello Bunch of Interns");
        }

    }
}

And this is the code on my Program.cs:
using backendApp.Data;
using backendApp.Middleware;
using backendApp.Services;
using backendApp.Services.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using SoapCore;
using SoapCore.Extensibility;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{ 
    options.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
    ServerVersion.AutoDetect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    options.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.None);
});

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);

builder.Services.AddSoapCore();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IInternUtilityService, InternUtilityService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFaultExceptionTransformer, FaultExceptionTransformer>();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();


builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});


builder.Services.AddHttpClient("NoSSLValidation")
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        return handler;
    });


var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

   
// UseSoaps Configurations...

app.Urls.Add("http://*:5879");
//App Runner
app.Run();

Note: I am using Visual Studio Community 2022 on Windows 10, with all allowed rules to that specific port on the Firewall (UDP and TCP)
I have been using the command curl -X GET http://localhost:5879/api/Intern/listthemall to test any requests to ListAllInterns() on InternController.cs in which i was expecting to receive the string:
Hello Bunch of Interns

http://localhost:5254 vs app.Urls.Add("http://*:5879"); - spot the difference

@Dai the command mentioned on top is from ChatGPT, where it showed me that port, but already modified to 5879 when testing the curl command !

What output are you getting from curl?

@IdrisBouar "the command mentioned on top is from ChatGPT" - ChatGPT can't help you here.

@IdrisBouar when running the program which did u choose http/https/iis?

@Dai I jumped to ChatGPT when this problem became illogical and shouldn't be existing.

@JerdineSabio i am using http debugging with SSL disabled !

Would adding a https port like app.Urls.Add("https://*:6969"); help?

@PekoMiko already tried using https, still no response from it.

does it work if you access the same url in the browser?

seems like this should work if you remove the SOAP stuff.  Are you using SOAP or standard Web API calls?

Comment out the following line of code and curl will work.
//app.UseHttpsRedirection();


According to your description, I create a sample in my side, and found I can access the url http://localhost:5062/api/Test/listthemall directly in browser, but not in curl command.
Then I found it will force to use https, and the ListAllInterns method will not be executed.
Here is my Program.cs.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});


builder.Services.AddHttpClient("NoSSLValidation")
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        return handler;
    });


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
app.UseAuthorization();

//app.MapControllers();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});


app.Run();


Already tried removing that line, still getting no response neither from Browser or curl.

Hi @IdrisBouar You mean you can't access in browser, please open the developer tools in browser, find the network tab, we need to check the http trace information.

could you guide me, what is the exact information I should extract it for you from the http trace ? (Headers ?)

The http request status code and the response .

Or you can create a repo which can reproduce the issue and share with me,  please hide the sensitve information, then I can check it. @IdrisBouar

I get the 404 Not Found code and nothing on the Response Header or on the Response tab content (I am using Edge)

@IdrisBouar Please cpoy the url and share with us.

@IdrisBouar We have to double-check the url.

http://localhost:5879/api/Intern/listthemall

@IdrisBouar This is incredible. Can you share the repo? Be careful to hide your sensitive information. It’s best to create a new project from scratch.

here is link for the repo : https://github.com/IdrisBouar/OverFlowReposPosts
And i just noticed that the controller started working and receiving requests when removed app.UseStaticFiles(); on Program.cs.

Hello @IdrisBouar, I tried just now, it can work in my side without removing the UseStaticFiles middleware, I will check it tomorrow.

@JasonPan : Thanks for sharing your step-by-step methodology for debugging this sort of issue. Very informative!
